# GetUrlCacheEntryInfo usage

Tags: c#, c++, geturl

I tried to print out the information given by the function called "GetUrlCacheEntryInfo" but it's not working, it's printing me out only a character in the debug - log. How can i print all the data correctly?

Comment: Can you provide a code example of how you are calling it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample, with an url (https://h6.msn.com/library/8.8/dapmsn.js) that I found in my cache (since I don't use IE this was the first I got from `FindFirstUrlCacheEntry`. The possbile issue why you could be printing only one character is that maybe you are not using wide string print functions. The `lpszSourceUrlName` and `lpszLocalFileName` fields are wide string fields so you should print them accordingly (see usage of `std::cout` and `std::wcout` in the sample below).

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Wininet.h>

#include <memory>

#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet.lib")

#include <iostream>

bool GetUrlCacheEntryInfo(const wchar_t* pUrl, std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>& pUrlCacheEntryInfo, DWORD nBufferSize = sizeof(INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO))
{
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> pTemporaryUrlCacheEntryInfo(new unsigned char[nBufferSize]);
    if (GetUrlCacheEntryInfo(pUrl, reinterpret_cast<LPINTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO>(pTemporaryUrlCacheEntryInfo.get()), &nBufferSize) == FALSE)
    {
        const DWORD nError = GetLastError();
        if (nError == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            pTemporaryUrlCacheEntryInfo.reset(new unsigned char[nBufferSize]);
            if (GetUrlCacheEntryInfo(pUrl, reinterpret_cast<LPINTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO>(pTemporaryUrlCacheEntryInfo.get()), &nBufferSize) == FALSE)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    pUrlCacheEntryInfo = std::move(pTemporaryUrlCacheEntryInfo);
    return true;
}

void PrintUrlCacheEntryInfo(LPINTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO pUrlCacheEntryInfo)
{
    std::cout << "Cache Entry Info:\n\tSize: " << pUrlCacheEntryInfo->dwStructSize << "\n\tUrl: ";
    std::wcout << pUrlCacheEntryInfo->lpszSourceUrlName;
    std::cout << "\n\tLocal File:";
    std::wcout << pUrlCacheEntryInfo->lpszLocalFileName;
    std::cout << "\n\tType: ";
    switch (pUrlCacheEntryInfo->CacheEntryType)
    {
    case EDITED_CACHE_ENTRY:
        std::cout << "EDITED_CACHE_ENTRY";
        break;
    case SPARSE_CACHE_ENTRY:
        std::cout << "SPARSE_CACHE_ENTRY";
        break;
    case STICKY_CACHE_ENTRY:
        std::cout << "STICKY_CACHE_ENTRY";
        break;
    case TRACK_OFFLINE_CACHE_ENTRY:
        std::cout << "TRACK_OFFLINE_CACHE_ENTRY";
        break;
    case TRACK_ONLINE_CACHE_ENTRY:
        std::cout << "TRACK_ONLINE_CACHE_ENTRY";
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "UNKNOWN";
        break;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\tHeaders: ";
    std::wcout << pUrlCacheEntryInfo->lpHeaderInfo;
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const wchar_t* pUrl = L"https://h6.msn.com/library/8.8/dapmsn.js";
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> pUrlCacheEntryInfo;
    if (GetUrlCacheEntryInfo(pUrl, pUrlCacheEntryInfo))
    {
        PrintUrlCacheEntryInfo(reinterpret_cast<LPINTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO>(pUrlCacheEntryInfo.get()));
    }
    else
    {
        std::wcout << L"Cache entry for url " << pUrl << L" was  not found!\n";
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Ok, do you know why URLDownloadToFile is downloading the files in appdata (iecache) instead of downloading them directly to the specified path?

Comment: I asked about the geturlcacheentryinfo because i wanted to find out the locaton of the downloaded file and then move it

Comment: @GDaniel no idea, and since there is an explicit 
URLDownloadToCacheFile function I really dont know why 
URLDownloadToFile should put the file in cache. What is the return code? Are you providing the callback interface as the last argument?

Comment: Currently i'm not home (at my pc) but when i'll be i'll debug it again and print the result here for you.

Comment: Done, look here http://pastebin.com/9As4Pew5. The problem is that the downloaded file isn't going to the correct path, even though i specified the path in the URLDownloadToFile func. (so the file is downloaded successfuly but it's going to ..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\). I hope you'll understand, if not please tell me, thanks!